# How to visualize computed path in planner_server in Nav2 with only map_server in nav2?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros2, nav2

my goal is to only visualize the computed path in nav2 given a pre-loaded map.
How to do this without launching other uncessary nodes such as the controller server since I don't have a robot to work with, I only needed the computed path.

Things I tried:

1. Loaded the pre-generated map via map server

> ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server --ros-args -p
> yaml_filename:=/my/path --ros-args -p use_sim_time:=true

2. Run the life cycle commands of map_server

> /ros2 lifecycle set /map_server configure
> and ros2 lifecycle set /map_server activate

3. Run the planner_server

> ros2 run nav2_planner planner_server --ros-args --params-file
> /my/params.yaml

4. Run the life cycle commands of planner_server

> /ros2 lifecycle set /planner_server configure
> and ros2 lifecycle set /planner_server activate

5. Opened rviz2, visualized the map, and set the initial and goal pose.

After these steps, i expect a plan topic published from the planner server but I don't get any. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings? I'm guessing you do.

Comment: yes, apologies, i have an error upon launching the planner_server only. It needs a map->base_link transform, so that's why I provided it with tf2 static transform publisher node. Even with that added, it still doesn't output a path. 
Additionally, here's a YouTube video of the entire process I tried: [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs2w0bsuTHI)

Comment: is bt_navigator not needed in this situation?